# android WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading()

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Hi this doesnt work for me:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    s="url clicked: "+url;
    view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, s, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    return true;
}
});
```

I have  links in my html, it shows during loading in main activity,

but when I click them I get a white blank screen

I want to be able to read what those urls are, in the program, and I assume this url override function is the purpose for this.

I have tried with loadData() as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing the new url to the WebView.
Should be

```
 view.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, null, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

**Edit**: This also gives me a blank screen because loadDataWithBaseUrl expects you to provide some text or html as the `data` parameter yourself. Just use

```
view.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was a different issue, i wrote the urls withotu http:// in my links. loaddatawithbaseurl(null, html, ...) does work, I found it among numerous examples, it works now, thank you.

Comment: loadurl(url) is valid, loaddata(html, ..) is valid loaddatawithbaseurl(url, html ...) is valid, loaddatawithbaseurl(null,html ...) is also valid it just ignores it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't write http:// in my links, and wrote only x. This was the problem, it works now.